# How can I use NSAlert with no icon?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsalert

I want to use this method

```
- (void)beginSheetModalForWindow:(NSWindow *)window modalDelegate:(id)delegate didEndSelector:(SEL)didEndSelector contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;
```

I found that NSAlert has this method. However, NSAlert will always come with its icon and its header text. Can I get rid of both of them and just have only my custom view?

Comment: Nope. A system (Cocoa) alert, at the moment, always shows the application icon and needs the standard message text.

Comment: Oh,thx.. Btw, I found that using custom sheets might help

Answer (score 4):

You can do some hack:

[image]

Here I have used a transparent image, [click here to download](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/6143821/transparent-image-2k?da=y).

Comment: That's a definitely smart approach. However shouldn't there be a more Cocoa-friendly way of achieving something that simple?!